# ICollection<Photo> generate different tables for different classes?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4.1, fluent

### Code

```
public class Subsidiary
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Photo> Photos { get; set; }
}

public class Party
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Photo> Photos { get; set; }
}

public class Photo
{
    public string FileName { get; set; }
}
```

To generate the database schema use the Fluent API.

```
public class PartyConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Party>
{
    public PartyConfiguration()
    {
        HasMany(p => p.Photos).WithRequired().WillCascadeOnDelete();

    }
}

public class SubsidiaryConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Subsidiary>
{
    public SubsidiaryConfiguration()
    {
        HasMany(p => p.Photos).WithRequired().WillCascadeOnDelete();
    }
}
```

### Error

So I run my application, the following error appears

> Model compatibility cannot be checked because the database does not
>   contain model metadata. Ensure that IncludeMetadataConvention has been
>   added to the DbModelBuilder conventions.

### Problem

I need for each class (`Subsidiary` and `Party`) is **generated a new table.**
In this case a table `PartyPhotos` and  `SubsidiaryPhotos` be created.

**How to make this setting with the EF FluentAPI??**

Thank you all for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try configuring Many-to-many configuration manually.

```
public class PartyConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Party>
{
    public PartyConfiguration()
    {
        HasMany(p => p.Photos).WithMany()
        .Map(m => 
          {
             m.ToTable("PartyPhotos");
             m.MapLeftKey("PartyId");
             m.MapRightKey("PhotoId");
          });

    }
}

public class SubsidiaryConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Subsidiary>
{
    public SubsidiaryConfiguration()
    {
        HasMany(p => p.Photos).WithMany()
        .Map(m => 
          {
             m.ToTable("SubsidiaryPhotos");
             m.MapLeftKey("SubsidiaryId");
             m.MapRightKey("PhotoId");
          });
    }
}
```

Comment: **Error** `The navigation property 'Photos' is not a declared property on type 'Party'. Verify that it has not been explicitly excluded from the model and that it is a valid navigation property.`   

The relationship should be: **one to many**
A Subsidiary has multiple photos
A party has multiple photos

Comment: EF creates the tables in this schema:
`Photos` Table,  
`SubsidiaryPhotos` table (relationship with `Photos`),    
`PartyPhotos` table (relationship with `Photos`)    
**Photos I would like the table did not exist in this scheme**
In this case `SubsidiaryPhotos` and `PhotosPhotos` and have the whole structure of the table `Photos` (**Two tables duplicate**)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you delete your database first then re-run the project.

Update: How about adding this to your class that derives from DbContext

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder) 
{
    modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<IncludeMetadataConvention>();
}
```

Comment: The problem is not access to the database.
I already removed the database and the same error occurs!!